# В чем разница между передачей ссылки структуры функции,или просто структуру?

Tags: c++, функции, указатели, ссылки

Возможно,вопрос был вам непонятен. Я не смог его нормально сформулировать)) Простите.
Допустим у нас есть структура:

```
struct golf {
    char fullname[Len];
    int handicap;
};
```

Также у нас есть функция,которая запрашивает ввод от пользователя ,для заполнения этой структуры:

```
static int setgolf(golf& g) {
    std::cout << "Vvedite handicap: ";
    std::cin >> g.handicap;
    std::cout << "Vvedite ima: ";
    std::cin.get(g.fullname, Len);
}
```

Что лучше нам передать функции setgolf(). Ссылку на структуру или саму структуру,чтобы программа работала быстрее.

Comment: Если вы передадите "саму структуру" - то что это будет? Копия? Тогда вы заполните копию, и по завершению функции она будет просто уничтожена (если вы не скопируете ее еще куда-то).

Comment: Что значит "передать саму структуру"? Приведите пример. И почему в заголовке вопроса и в примере - ссылка,  а в тексте речь идет про какой-то "указатель"? Откуда вдруг взялся указатель? И как вы собрались передавать в эту функцию указатель, если она требует ссылку?

Comment: Если функция принимает ссылку на структуру, то как вы собрались передавать туда что-то еще?

Comment: Обращаться к обьекту по указателью или по ссыльке не  делает никакой разницы. Если вы обращаетесь к конкретному адресу, просто не имеет смысла держать в программе еще один обьект(указатель) для хранения адреса обьекта

Comment: Я имею ввиду,что при передаче полностью структуры - создается полная копия структура,а это затрачивает время и память. Что если я передам ссылку(адрес) структуры,тогда мне не придется копировать и затрачивать время. Я спрашиваю,что из этого ЛУЧШЕ!

Comment: Еще  нужно учесть, что значение указателья  можно изменить, присвоив адрес другого адреса или присвоив нулевой указатель, а ссылька всегда будет ссылаться на тот же обьект. Какой вариант вас устроит, решать вам в зависимости от задачи. Если вы хотите работать с конкретным обьектом,  передайте по ссыльке

Comment: Интересно, всегда удивляют глобальные вопросы - что использовать, A, B или C? Если бы был единственный ответ, думаю. создатели языка все остальные способы выбросили бы, нет?

Comment: @TEARLESS: Вопрос в первую очередь в том, что вам *нужно*. А уже потом будем выбирать, что *лучше* из подходящих вариантов. Вы привели пример функции, которая по своей сути должна менять передаваемую извне структуру. В таком случае передача структуры по значению **не подходит в принципе**. О каком "лучше" может идти речь?

Comment: @Harry, а  если один обьект(суперробот) решал бы все задачи!..  Были времена, когда идею о  полете человека в космосе считали вздором...